# Error Using Coder in Swift 3

Tags: nsuserdefaults, swift3, nsobject, encoder

I am trying to add an "Event" through an @IOButton using NSUserDefaults.

Before I upgraded to Swift 3 my code was running fine. Using the "convert" helper from Xcode, I was still able to run the code no problems.

I have further updated the version to meet the Swift 3 syntax and now I am getting an error have updated the syntax and I cannot figure out why I am getting an error when I try to encode my object.

Code converted through Xcode that runs without an error:
    //object
    import Foundation
    class CalendarEvent : NSObject {
        var title : String
        var dateString : String

```
    init(withTitle t : String, andDateString ds : String) {
        title = t
        dateString = ds
    }
    //get values out of NSUserDefaults
    init(withCoder coder : NSCoder) {
        dateString = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "dateString") as! String
        title = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
    }
    //time to put CalendarEvent into NSUserDefaults Key-Value store
    func encodeWithCoder(_ coder : NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(dateString, forKey: "dateString")
        coder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
    }
}


//button action
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender : UIBarButtonItem) {

    let newEvent = "Test Event \(events.count + 1)"
    let defaultsKey = "\(monthNumber)-\(dayNumber)"
    let ce = CalendarEvent(withTitle: newEvent, andDateString: defaultsKey)

    let encodedCE = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ce)
    events.append(encodedCE as AnyObject)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(events, forKey: defaultsKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Updated code that gives an error:

```
//object
class CalendarEvent: NSObject {
    var title : String
    var dateString : String

    init(withTitle t: String, andDateString ds: String) {
        title = t
        dateString = ds
    }

    required init(coder : NSCoder) {
        dateString = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "dateString") as! String
        title = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder : NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(dateString, forKey: "dateString")
        coder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
    }
}


//button action
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    let newEvent = "Test Event \(events.count+1)"
    let defaultsKey = "\(monthNum)-\(dayNum)"
    let ce = CalendarEvent(withTitle: newEvent, andDateString: defaultsKey)

    // where the error occurs
    let encodedCE = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ce)
    events.append(encodedCE as AnyObject)

    UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: defaultsKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Console Output:

```
1-1
2016-10-07 19:39:26.152 Swift3_TableView_CalApp[1400:287793] -[Swift3_TableView_CalApp.CalendarEvent encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800026ebc0
2016-10-07 19:39:26.171 Swift3_TableView_CalApp[1400:287793] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift3_TableView_CalApp.CalendarEvent encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800026ebc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d3d34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010279e21e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102dacf34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cc2c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cc2798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x00000001022d755c _encodeObject + 1263
6   Foundation                          0x000000010230c29a +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 156
7   Swift3_TableView_CalApp             0x00000001021ad1b0 _TFC23Swift3_TableView_CalApp12SingleDayTVC16addButtonPressedfT6senderCSo15UIBarButtonItem_T_ + 976
8   Swift3_TableView_CalApp             0x00000001021ad7aa _TToFC23Swift3_TableView_CalApp12SingleDayTVC16addButtonPressedfT6senderCSo15UIBarButtonItem_T_ + 58
9   UIKit                               0x0000000103162b88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
10  UIKit                               0x00000001035a384d -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 149
11  UIKit                               0x0000000103162b88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
12  UIKit                               0x00000001032e82b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
13  UIKit                               0x00000001032e85cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
14  UIKit                               0x00000001032e8755 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 838
15  UIKit                               0x00000001032e74c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
16  UIKit                               0x00000001031d00d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
17  UIKit                               0x00000001031d17c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
18  UIKit                               0x000000010317ea33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
19  UIKit                               0x0000000103970b6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
20  UIKit                               0x0000000103969817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ce2311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cc759c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cc6a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cc6494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
25  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001072e6a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
26  UIKit                               0x0000000103160f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
27  Swift3_TableView_CalApp             0x00000001021a913f main + 111
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010636768d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What am I no seeing????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func encodeWithCoder(coder : NSCoder) {
```

has been renamed in Swift 3 to

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
```